# What are the options for storing login credentials for Google Drive? Locally as well as serverside

Tags: google-drive-api

I read the Google Drive API Documentation on Authorize Requests but honestly I was confused. 
All I want to be able to do is periodically download a file, modify it and upload it again on Google Drive. My App which does this runs as a cron job weekly. So all this has to be unattended.

How do I automatically login to my Google  Drive Account and access my files?

I tried the Quickstart python script but that prompts me to go to the URL and copy the code and paste it on the CLI. This requires manual intervention and I would like to circumvent that.

Thanks.
-Utpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the credential data locally after the first time you initiate the authenticate, and later read from the credential data for authentication.
Here is the sample code with python SDK.

```
    # get credential
    client_id     = YOUR_CLIENT_ID
    client_secret = YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
    flow = oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, \
           client_secret, GOOGLE_DRIVE_SCOPE)

    # try get credential from credential file
    storage    = oauth2client.file.Storage(cred_file)
    credential = storage.get()

    # no credential file exists
    if credential is None or credential.invalid:
        credential = oauth2client.tools.run(flow, storage)
```

I've never played with raw HTTP requests, so if this is not what you want, you can download and hack google API python SDK yourself.

Comment: Hi Summer_More_More_Tea...this code worked..thanks..but today I am getting HTTPError 400 Invalid Upload Request when I try the same code...strange..I have posted the question in a separate thread just now..